# Cómo evitar la alerta de reenvío de formulario al recargar la página (PHP)

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema que a la mayoría les ha sucedido y que les sucede aún, he probado el `header('Location: ejemplo.php')` y me ha funcionado, pero quiero arreglar el problema en el mismo `$_POST` del código PHP.

Código PHP y HTML

```
        define('friendStatus', $users->userVar(USERNAME, 'block_newfriends'));
    define('tradeStatus', $users->userVar(USERNAME, $tradename));
    define('Motto', $db->real_escape_string($users->userVar(USERNAME, 'motto')));
    define('Pais', $users->userVar(USERNAME, 'pais'));
    if(isset($_POST['SaveSettings'])) {
        if(isset($_POST["FriendRequests"]) && friendStatus == 0) {
            $db->real_query("UPDATE `users` SET `block_newfriends` = '1' WHERE `username` = '" . USERNAME . "'");
            $tpl->assign('fr_checkvalues', "checked='checked' value='1'");
        }
        else if(!isset($_POST["FriendRequests"]) && friendStatus == 1) {
            $db->real_query("UPDATE `users` SET `block_newfriends` = '0' WHERE `username` = '" . USERNAME . "'");
        }
        else if(isset($_POST["TradeStatus"]) && tradeStatus == 0) {
            $db->real_query("UPDATE `users` SET `" . $tradename . "` = '1' WHERE `username` = '" . USERNAME . "'");
            $tpl->assign('trd_checkvalues', "checked='checked' value='1'");
        }
        else if(!isset($_POST["TradeStatus"]) && tradeStatus == 1) {
            $db->real_query("UPDATE `users` SET `" . $tradename . "` = '0' WHERE `username` = '" . USERNAME . "'");
        }
        else if(isset($_POST["Motto"]) && $_POST["Motto"] != Motto) {
            $db->real_query("UPDATE `users` SET `motto` = '" . $db->real_escape_string($_POST["Motto"]) . "' WHERE `username` = '" . USERNAME . "'");
            $tpl->assign('Motto', $db->real_escape_string($_POST["Motto"]));
        }
        else if(isset($_POST["paisType"])){
            $db->real_query("UPDATE `users` SET `pais` = '" . $_POST["paisType"] . "' WHERE `username` = '" . USERNAME . "'");
        }
                    $tpl->assign('success', $light->successMsg('Los cambios han sido guardados, refresca la página para verlos.'));
    }
    if(friendStatus == '1') {
        $tpl->assign('fr_checkvalues', "checked='checked' value='1'");
    }
    if(tradeStatus == '1') {
        $tpl->assign('trd_checkvalues', "checked='checked' value='1'");
    }
    $tpl->assign('motto', Motto);
    $tpl->assign('paisSelect', Pais);
}

<form method='post'>
    <strong>{$shortname} misión</strong><br>
<input type='text' name='Motto' maxlenth='32' value='{$motto}'><br><br>

    <strong>País</strong><br>
    <select name="paisType">
    <option value="Desconocido">Ninguno</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="ES">España</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
  </select><br>
    País seleccionado: {$paisSelect}<br><br>

    <input type='checkbox' name='FriendRequests' {$fr_checkvalues}> <b>Solicitudes de amistad</b> <br />
    <input type='checkbox' name='TradeStatus' {$trd_checkvalues}> <b>Tradeo</b> <br />
    <br />
    <input class="btblack" type='submit' name='SaveSettings' value='Cambiar'>
</form>
```

Al enviar el formulario funciona correctamente, pero al darle F5 o al recargar la página me muestra la ventana si deseo reenvíar el formulario. Cosa que no quiero y no logro solucionar. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: No se si te has equivocado copiando y pegando, o lo tienes mal, pero ese código PHP no va a funcionar nunca. Las variables `friendStatus` deben empezar con $ quedando como `$friendStatus`. Me aventuraría a corregirlo, pero es que está para volver a empezar todo el PHP. En cuanto al HTML en el option de colombia tienes mal puesto el value, te falta un = entre value y "co".

Comment: @JoseManuelMorales, lo del `<option value"co">Colombia</option>`, se me fue el "=" al copiar y pegar. Lo demás me funciona perfectamente ya que solo mostré una parte del código, las variables están definidas más arriba. ¿Sabrás cómo evitar el reenvío de formulario?

Comment: Pon el código necesario para que podamos reproducir el error. Ese código no está bien para funcionar. Por otro lado, si compruebas si se ha hecho un $_POST de paisType y que sea distinto de `empty` debería prevenir el envío.

Comment: @JoseManuelMorales, listo. Gracias de antemano igual.

Comment: Ahora le pego un vistazo. Sin los define cuesta saber que no te has equivocado en declarar variables.

Comment: Está bien, gracias.

Comment: Echale un vistazo a las respuestas de esta pregunta pueden serte de utilidad https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320113/how-to-prevent-form-resubmission-when-page-is-refreshed-f5-ctrlr